# PHP User tracking without cookies and IP

Tags: php, tracking

I need to track user but independent from browsers and IP address.
I googled about Flash Shared Objects, but I see it is not the best solution.
I tried to run `arp -a [IP]` but I am getting null, may be I am wrong but it seems the problem is that other computerss is not in the same network!?

IS any ideas? Thanks

PS. OS UBUNTU 11.04, Apache2, PHP 5.3

Comment: Without even IP how do you define a single user?

Comment: You cannot get the mac for the arbitrary IP it is not in the same network with you

Comment: Why do you need this? You have pretty much ruled out every tool there is to track users. What is your exact use case?

Comment: I see, but how to solve my problem? )

Comment: @Joeeee: what **is** your problem?

Comment: @Pekka @zerkms I just have a task from my customer and I need to implement it

Comment: @Joeee the task doesn't make sense. I don't see how this is worth spending any effort on answering if the root of the problem is a nonsensical requirement from a client. You should find out what the actual use case is first - Flash Storage and HTML 5 local storage are much less supported at the moment than the classical storage methods

Comment: It seems the only one solution is using Flash Shared Objects

Comment: @Pekka I see that it is no sense, but customer is crying about that :)

Comment: @Joeeee: So tell your customer that they don't understand what they're talking about.

Comment: You need to ask the customer what their reasons are. Find out why they want to do this with these limitations and you might be able to solve their real problem. (Given the timing, I would guess it has something to do with the new EU (and the UK implementation of them specifically) [laws on tracking](http://www.ico.gov.uk/~/media/documents/library/Privacy_and_electronic/Practical_application/advice_on_the_new_cookies_regulations.pdf) but they cover the act of tracking, not the technology used to do it so "not cookies" wouldn't solve that problem.)

Comment: @Pekka I am at one point with you. thanks.

Comment: assuming that woodscreative's answer won't work there is no ethical reason to do what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to create a session token and pass it to every URL on your site (old school)